# Namespace Issue with WCF Data Contract / Design Problem?

Tags: wcf, service, datacontract

I am having multiple Services in my application.i have a datacontract that i need to use in more than 1 service.

Eg: class `myCommonClass` is being used in 2 of my services `service1` and `service2`

To do this, at a service level, i have a `MyApplication.Common` library and this library contains `myCommonClass`. Since both my services have a reference to `MyApplication.Common`, they can both use it.

My client application has service references to both `service1` and `service2`. 
To my client application, `service1.myCommonClass` is a separate namespace as compared to `service2.myCommonClass` and **therein lies my problem**

In my Reference.cs (generated via svcutil - the namespace of BOTH classes is the **same** i.e.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute
(Name="MyCommonClass", Namespace="http://A.B.MyCommonClassNamespace")])
```

However, both of these are in 2 separate `reference.cs` files and the namespaces in the `reference.cs` is different due to being part of two separate service references.

Hence, to my client application they appear as two completely unrelated classes.

**Question 1 ** :  Is there any way that can i indicate to my client application that `service1.myCommonClass` and  `service2.myCommonClass` are inherently the same class?

**Question 2 ** : Is there something inherently wrong with my design here for me to run 
into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your design is fine. Instead of adding service reference from Visual Studio, generate the proxy class using svcutil on the command prompt. Create a class library project and add the generated .cs files to it. You can create a batch file and run it in pre build step as well.
Use svcutil as below  to generate the proxy class in a single file from service dll (the dll that implements your two service)

```
svcutil.exe /t:metadata "PATH\service1.dll" "PATH\service2.dll"  
svcutil.exe /t:code *.wsdl *.xsd /o:Proxy.cs
```

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try this out and update on how it goes.